# How do we refer to "whose absence" when it's an object instead of a person?

Tags: grammar

**Explanation of what I'm trying to communicate:**

Suppose that there is an object, Vinegar (say).

And we're marinating chicken before roasting it. If vinegar was added to the marinade then the roast turns out to be good. If it wasn't, then it's going to be smelly and "rubbery".

Now let's say that I didn't know this and some person X found out about the requirement of vinegar and informed me.

**My sentence:**

"Today, I added a new ingredient, Vinegar, in the marinade, whose absence causes chicken to be smelly, found by person X".

Is the above sentence correct? It feels somewhat off. I have 2 queries regarding this:

1) Is the phrase **"whose absence"** correct? If not then what other phrase can we use in its place?

2) Is there a **better way to frame this whole sentence** rather than breaking it into smaller sentences (for the sake of improving grammar)?

Comment: I added a new ingredient, Vinegar, in the marinade, without which, X discovered, chicken can be smelly.

Comment: @aparente001 Beautiful! Thanks!